# Inline checkboxes with django-crispy

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm using django `ModelForm` and `django-crispy-forms` to create beautiful bootstrap forms.

I didn't find any way to generate inline checkboxes like the [one available here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

Even using crispy FormHelper(), no way do define fields like:

```
Field('checkbox1', css_class="inline"),
Field('checkbox2', css_class="inline"),
Field('checkbox3', css_class="inline"),
```

where `checkbox1`, `checkbox2` and `checkbox3` are defined in the model as `model.BooleanField`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of django-crispy-forms and all I can say is that this is not currently supported. I will try to work on a patch as soon as possible, I will keep you posted.

**UPDATE 2012/9/24**

django-crispy-forms 1.2.0 has been released today and includes a `bootstrap.InlineCheckboxes` layout object, for rendering Django `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widgets with inline checkboxes. I'm not currently planning on supporting a layout object for rendering several BooleanFields this way. That makes probably more sense as a custom personal layout object.

Comment: OK thanks. I found a way to do, using HTML inside the Layout and a Field with a custom template.